# git: partially restore previous version of a file

Tags: git

In a project I'm currently working on, I have a file with roughly the following history:

1. It started as a copy of a file from a different project
2. Some changes where made
3. Somewhere in between the majority of the file was deemed unnecessary and deleted
4. After that, existing lines where modified and additionally new lines where created either by copying from the original file or as completely new lines that where not in the original file.

Now, I regret having deleted the vast majority of the file and I want to revert back to the initial file (some 100 commits ago) but with all modifications except the deletions since then.

In other words: Every line that exists in the latest commit should be taken from that, every line that's not in there should be taken from the first commit.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: sounds like you might want to have a look at cherry-picking. I don't have time now to go in more details, but create a "recovery" branch, cherry pick the commits (apparently you committed very often, that's good), merge them, check it all, then merge it all back on master.

Comment: You may be able to simply run `git revert` on the deletion commit. Note that this might affect multiple files; if so, you can fix each file you don't want changed using the advice `git status` gives, or use other Git tools to just undo the deletion in the one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a third-party tool to show you the initial file and the current file side by side and just perform the fix manually. It's unlikely that there's any automatic solution; you could `git checkout --merge` the original file from that first commit, but if you're unlucky you might not get a merge conflict, and if you're lucky and you do get merge conflict it's unlikely that it would be a very good place to work from.